# A query to pick out the highest ten values, or the highest 10%, from groups within a table

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a database of a large number of users, logging where they live and how many times they have logged into the site. I'm looking to find out the most active users in each city.

I know how to find the single most active user in each city:

```
select user_id, city, max(login_count)
from user
group by city
```

But it would be very useful to be able to find the 10 most active users for each city. Or even, more usefully, but I suspect maybe not possible in SQL, the top 10% in terms of activity.

If anyone could give an idea of how to complete either, or both tasks, I'd greatly appreciate it.

I'm using Navicat to connect to a MySQL server for this task.

Comment: FWIW, **your current query can return bad results**.  Since you don't group on `user_id` as well, the `user_id` you get may or may not be related to the `max(login_count`.  Other RDBMS's besides MySQL force you to group all your non-aggregates for just that reason.

Comment: You should find your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+mysql

Comment: Hi JNK, thanks very much for that response - something I completely didn't know. Would you mind quickly explaining how you would change the query to avert this problem? I tried grouping by user_id too, but the results were quite strange...

Answer (score 1):

if you are using MySql you can use the SELECT TOP 10 PERCENT statement.

like

```
select top 10 percent * from (
    select user_id, city, max(login_count)
    from user
    group by user_id,city
    order by max(login_count))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the top 10 as:

```
select user_id
     , city
     , login_count
  from user
 group by user_id
     , city
 order by city
     , login_count desc
 limit 10
```

I wouldn't want to run that query very often because it will be quite slow as will require a filesort on a temp table if you were to look at the explain plan.

Comment: that query doesnt make sense. any chance you can add an explanation what it does?

Comment: @Imre did you mean to post this comment on the answer provided by @Joe because that query doesn't make any sense :)

Comment: This will only return the top 10 and not top 10 *per city*